# Connexion refused and CrashLoopBackOff Running Loop for Container with Docker GraphQl

Tags: mongodb, docker, vue.js, kubernetes, graphql

I'm new with docker, i got this error i'm using AMZ platform with mongoDB and graphql with Docker everything was working fine cause i didn't wright all the code, and boum i constantly get running and CrashLoopBackOff all the times :( i don't know whyyyy ! This is what I getting:

```
graphql-564c895966-25c2w   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          20m
graphql-564c895966-6g64n   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   9          20m

kubectl describe pod graphql-564c895966-25c2w:

Name:         graphql-564c895966-25c2w
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         pool-g1r6uxpbs-3yjla/10.131.59.199
Start Time:   Thu, 25 Jun 2020 00:46:05 +0100
Labels:       app=graphql
              pod-template-hash=564c895966
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.0.143
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.0.143
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/graphql-564c895966
Containers:
  graphql:
    Container ID:   docker://05feb2a4feefbffcd31e23cd4b80fe5cdc3c6dbb5559a9372015ebdf789432b1
    Image:          fundinginvoicetech/gql:a917d80b5f276e8307e9993811f73569694fa56a
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://fundinginvoicetech/gql@sha256:805762b32727ce0cbd20250c35002419df189a79f492281b59681117c53273a7
    Port:           4000/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Thu, 25 Jun 2020 01:01:45 +0100
      Finished:     Thu, 25 Jun 2020 01:02:25 +0100
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  9
    Liveness:       http-get https://:https/healthz delay=15s timeout=40s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      NODE_ENV:                  production
      PORT:                      4000
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID:         <set to the key 'amazonAccountId' in secret 'secrets'>  Optional: false
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY:     <set to the key 'amazonSecret' in secret 'secrets'>     Optional: false
      SENTRY_DSN:                <set to the key 'sentryDsn' in secret 'secrets'>        Optional: false
      ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN:  <set to the key 'logzToken' in secret 'secrets'>        Optional: false
      ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL:    <set to the key 'logzUrl' in secret 'secrets'>          Optional: false
      ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME:  <set to the key 'logzServiceName' in secret 'secrets'>  Optional: false
      AUTH_PUBLIC_KEY:           <set to the key 'authPublicKey' in secret 'secrets'>    Optional: false
      PRIVATE_KEY:               <set to the key 'privatekey' in secret 'cert'>          Optional: false
      CERTIFICATE:               <set to the key 'certificate' in secret 'cert'>         Optional: false
      CA_CERT:                   <set to the key 'ca' in secret 'cert'>                  Optional: false
      MONGO_CONNECT_URL:         <set to the key 'mongo' in secret 'databases'>          Optional: false
      POSTGRES_CONNECT_URL:      <set to the key 'pg' in secret 'databases'>             Optional: false
      ENGINE_API_KEY:            <set to the key 'apolloEngineAPI' in secret 'secrets'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-m69fd (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-m69fd:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-m69fd
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From                           Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----                           -------
  Normal   Scheduled  <unknown>            default-scheduler              Successfully assigned default/graphql-564c895966-25c2w to pool-g1r6uxpbs-3yjla
  Normal   Pulling    20m                  kubelet, pool-g1r6uxpbs-3yjla  Pulling image "fundinginvoicetech/gql:a917d80b5f276e8307e9993811f73569694fa56a"
  Normal   Pulled     20m                  kubelet, pool-g1r6uxpbs-3yjla  Successfully pulled image "fundinginvoicetech/gql:a917d80b5f276e8307e9993811f73569694fa56a"
  Normal   Created    18m (x4 over 20m)    kubelet, pool-g1r6uxpbs-3yjla  Created container graphql
  Normal   Started    18m (x4 over 20m)    kubelet, pool-g1r6uxpbs-3yjla  Started container graphql
  Warning  Unhealthy  18m (x9 over 20m)    kubelet, pool-g1r6uxpbs-3yjla  Liveness probe failed: Get https://10.244.0.143:4000/healthz: dial tcp 10.244.0.143:4000: connect: connection refused
  Normal   Killing    18m (x3 over 19m)    kubelet, pool-g1r6uxpbs-3yjla  Container graphql failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Pulled     5m40s (x8 over 19m)  kubelet, pool-g1r6uxpbs-3yjla  Container image "fundinginvoicetech/gql:a917d80b5f276e8307e9993811f73569694fa56a" already present on machine
  Warning  BackOff    30s (x67 over 16m)   kubelet, pool-g1r6uxpbs-3yjla  Back-off restarting failed container

kubectl logs graphql-564c895966-6g64n

yarn run v1.22.4
$ node index.js
{"message":"Starting server with args []...","level":"info"}
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason:
Error: only absolute urls are supported
    at /home/graphql/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js:54:10
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at new Fetch (/home/graphql/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js:49:9)
    at Fetch (/home/graphql/node_modules/node-fetch/index.js:37:10)
    at module.exports (/home/graphql/node_modules/isomorphic-fetch/fetch-npm-node.js:8:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/graphql/index.js:88:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
{"message":"External IP 104.248.164.113","level":"info"}
```

and this is my manifest.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: graphql
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: graphql
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: graphql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: graphql
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: graphql
          image: fundinginvoicetech/gql:$COMMIT_SHA1
          ports:
            - containerPort: 4000
              name: https
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthz
              port: https
              scheme: HTTPS
              httpHeaders:
                - name: $HEALTH_CHECK_HEADER
                  value: $HEALTH_CHECK_TOKEN
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 40
          env:
            - name: NODE_ENV
              value: "production"
            - name: PORT
              value: "4000"
            - name: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: amazonAccountId
            - name: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: amazonSecret
            - name: SENTRY_DSN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: sentryDsn
            - name: ELASTIC_APM_SECRET_TOKEN
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: logzToken
            - name: ELASTIC_APM_SERVER_URL
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: logzUrl
            - name: ELASTIC_APM_SERVICE_NAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: logzServiceName
            - name: AUTH_PUBLIC_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: authPublicKey
            - name: PRIVATE_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cert
                  key: privatekey
            - name: CERTIFICATE
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cert
                  key: certificate
            - name: CA_CERT
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: cert
                  key: ca
            - name: MONGO_CONNECT_URL
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: databases
                  key: mongo
            - name: POSTGRES_CONNECT_URL
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: databases
                  key: pg
            - name: ENGINE_API_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: secrets
                  key: apolloEngineAPI
            - name: ENGINE_SCHEMA_TAG
              value: "production"
            - name: HEALTH_CHECK_HEADER
              value: $HEALTH_CHECK_HEADER
            - name: HEALTH_CHECK_TOKEN
              value: $HEALTH_CHECK_TOKEN
            - name: IP_AUTODETECTION_METHOD
              value: "interface=eth.*"
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: regcred
```

**Please can someone can help me i can't find anything :((((((((((**

Comment: the error is right there {"message":"connection error:Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist:

Comment: what is your connection url? can you telnet from the pod to the mongo atlas db ?

Comment: thank you to reply to me :) it's write connection error:Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB but i got a whitelist set up with my IP so i don't know why is doing that

Comment: i use ip: 0.0.0.0/0 and the message disappear but i got still the error : only absolute urls are supported :((((((

Comment: okay, have you googled the difference between normal mongo url and absolute mongo url ? :)

Comment: yes i'm using a .env to display the MONGO_CONNECT_URL

Comment: which has the value of ?

Comment: `mongodb+srv://xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx@fundinginvoice-xxxxx.mongodb.net/fundinginvoice`

Comment: i'm using some certificate aswell if you have a look for the api http://gql.fudninginvoice.com/ the connexion is not anymore secure aswell, and i juste change the certificate 1 month ago

Comment: it is a mongo db cluster am i correct?

Comment: yes it is const connect = () => (mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_CONNECT_URL, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useCreateIndex: true,
}));

Comment: `app.use('/graphql', jwt({ secret: publicKey }), graphqlHTTP((request) => ({
      schema: executableSchema,
      context: { pgPool, user: request.user },
      graphiql: !production,
      customFormatErrorFn(error) {
        global.logger.error(error);
        Sentry.captureException(error);
        return error;
      },
    })));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was all about connecting the right IP on aws EC2 to get the right access

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you are trying to connect to a mongocluster you need o use this uri:

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]
```

For example:

Standalone (Not a mongo db cluster)

```
mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017
```

Replicaset

```
mongodb://mongodb1.example.com:27317,mongodb2.example.com:27017/?replicaSet=mySet&authSource=authDB
```

Comment: i tried to run the server graphql and i get this error `error: connection error:Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the database from an IP that isn't whitelisted.` and of course there is my IP in the whitelist and i try boof my IP and 0.0.0/0

Comment: i'm sure is about certification cause the connection is closed that the principal error cause as i said when going to the API on the web there is no connexion secure, and we got an Https from Amazon

Comment: the uri is fine cause i get the connexion when i run the server by him self is just really about the docker, it is not doing the connexion between them, and i'm using certificate on top of that...

Comment: did you follow this ? https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/connect-to-mongodb-atlas/

Comment: No i didn't try with studio 3T

Comment: Read the "Get the connection string from mongo atlas" part not the studio 3t

Comment: okay stutio 3T is to read to DB i just downloded and connect my self easyli. Me i'm using dataGrip with amazon witch releated with mongoDB and graphql....

Comment: please understand my previous comment

Comment: and i'm fine with this what i suppose to see ?

Comment: and i use this mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@fundinginvoice-f6u7s.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority and is working fine